# Говорить языком или на языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Казалось бы, все просто: говорят НА языке. На русском, на английском и т.д. Но как же быть тогда со знаменитыми строчками Маяковского "Я русский бы выучил только за то, что им разговаривал Ленин"? Или это просто, так сказать, поэтическая вольность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. +1 автору.

**Behemothus** в своём ответе привёл фразу **"Я тебе русским языком говорю"**. Думаю, это старорусский оборот речи. 
Например, в украинском языке, где сохранились *некоторые* старорусские особенности, говорится: "Я розмовляю українською мовою" (я разговариваю на украинском языке). Т.е. кем? чем? -- українською, англійською и т.п.

Думаю, в русском языке на разговорном уровне сохранилась такая старинная особенность. "Говорю русским языком" параллельно с "говорю на русском языке".

Comment: Нередко в разговорном языке существует несколько вариантов, как можно сказать одно и то же разными словами. А в **литературный** образец, норму, может войти какой-то один вариант. 

Например, по памяти (может, какую-то букву не так напишу), могу сказать, что в таких славянских языках, как хорватский и польский, аналогичная фраза выглядит так, если кириллицей написать.

"Говорим НА хрватском"  и "по-польску".

В русском языке же существует, например, и третий вариант, кроме тех, что в вопросе. **"Я говорю по-русски"**.

Answer (score 4):

Я не вижу здесь прямой игры слов в том направлении, о котором говорит Людмила.
Т.е. она есть, но немного другая. 
"Я тебе русским языком говорю" не вызывает сомнений.
Но если языком можно говорить, почему им нельзя разговаривать?
Думаю, у Маяковского намек именно на это.
Про мышечный орган - как-то мелковато для Владимира Владимировича.

Answer (score 2):

У нас 3 омонима: язык-1-мышечный орган, участвующий в образовании звуков, язык-2-средство общения(система фонетич., лексич. и грамматич. средств, речь, система знаков. язык 3 -народ, нация). Маяковский совместил 2 значения, применил художественное средство : имел в виду язык как мышечный орган, им разговаривал Ленин,а первая часть предложения использует омоним со знач."средство общения,система знаков русского языка". Получилась такая игра слов.

Answer (score 2):

Говорить КЕМ?/ЧЕМ? можно не только языком. Можно говорить глазами, взглядом, губами, жестами, стихами, прозой и т.д. А дальше уже можно добавлять и различные определения: нежным взглядом, непонятными жестами, русским языком, стихами Маяковского...

Comment: Народ начал растекаться мыслию по древу! Шизым орлом под облакы...

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, так раньше говорили. Вот вам пример из казённой книги по Курляндской губернии (А. Орановский. *Материалы для географии и статистики России: Курляндская губерния*. Петербург, 1862):

```
значительное число латышей, говорящих латышским языком
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А "разговаривать... языком"? Тоже употреблялось или все-таки это поэтическая вольность Маяковского?